# Android studio java WebSocket client-server

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have an application android and database mysql in server, in my app when the user authenticate his status in the database ONLINE, and when he go to logout his status change to OFFLINE,
Now i have a problem that when user uninstall the app without logout his status stays ONLINE
So, i wanted to make the user status offline in the database if he uninstall the application without logout, or when he turn off his network
Thanks,

Comment: *"nticate his status in the database ONLINE, and when he go to logout his status change to OFFLINE, Now i have a problem that when user uninstall the app without logout his status stays ONLINE So, i wanted to make the user status offline in the database if he uninstall the application without logout"* but a wild guess..  let the server and client play ping / pong over the network no pong answer from client force a logout ..

Comment: Hi Nijland, I have an app when the user of this app signin  successffully his status in the database change to Online and if he sigout from the app his status change to Offline, So the problem if the user not signout and uninstall the application from his phone, his status not change to Offline

Comment: So i want to update the status of the user of my application when he uninstall my application

Comment: yes like i said before without knowing your application code (android (Java)), backend (java/MySQL) code and or without telling which frameworks your are using there is no way to give more solid advice...  As it might be just as simple on the server to catch and handle a WebSocketException when a disconnect happens..

Comment: android / java, backend / laravel

Comment: what @RaymondNijland is trying to tell you, is that you have to post your current code in your question. this means you have to edit it to add in the code, till then nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: " but a wild guess.. let the server and client play ping / pong over the network no pong answer from client force a logout " HOW to do that

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks @a_local_nobody -> *"Proof-read before posting!

Now that you're ready to ask your question, take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense? Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question."* in this case we know **"nothing"** as source code  tells is more then million words....

Comment: ok, @RaymondNijland, can you give me an explication for the webSocket side server, and how to update a table in the database ?

Comment: you said to be using Laraval on the backend.. i assume you need to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#using-example-application and use [pusher](https://pusher.com/channels) or use [laraval echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)